# Is 'lowercase_separated_by_underscores' recommended for Javascript variable naming convention?

Tags: javascript, naming-conventions

I am a Python programmer before learning Javascript, and as `lowercase_separated_by_underscores` is recommended for Python's variable naming,
I continued using it for programming Javascript since changing habit is painful and unconvenient. But after seeing a lot of
professional Javascript code which use lower camel case to name variables, I begin to think about
what is the most standard and suggested way, `this_way` or `thatWay` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The universally accepted naming convention for JavaScript is `lowerCamelCase`, yes.

Comment: Very clearly and certainly, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Well, have you taken a look at the DOM API? Or the built-in objects? Here are some methods names...

```
getElementById
forEach
addEventListener
toLowerCase
```

This should answer your concerns.